# How to include order comment in order confirmation email

Tags: magento-1.9, order-confirmation

same as title, how do I get order comment from checkout page to be included in the order confirmation email? I'm using Magento 1.9.

I can understand it is transactional email template that need to be edited.
But unfortunately I can't get the variable for order comment.

[image]